# SharePoint 2019 On Premise PIcture Gallery not showing up when adding a webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server

A Picture Gallery(Slide Show) was created via "Add an app" on the SharePoint site where it is to be placed. I see it in site contents (as a Picture Library) but when I go to add it on the page (add a webpart in column...) it is not available in the list. Why? Any direction is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Web part and list are two different concepts. List and Library are also different. Usually Library is used to store content. List is more functional. We can use list to create items and so on.

Please refer to these articles for more information:

[Introduction to lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-lists-0a1c3ace-def0-44af-b225-cfa8d92c52d7)

[Using web parts on SharePoint pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0)